# Ionic Cordova Speech Recognition not working when running in android version 9 or higher

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, speech-recognition

Ionic Cordova Speech Recognition working in android version 8 or lower. But whenever I am running running the app in android version 9 or higher google tap to speak is not showing.

[Emulator Tap To Speak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwWQu.png)

Also sharing the speech recognition code for better understanding:

```
getPermission() {
    this.speechRecognition.hasPermission().then((hasPermission: boolean) => {
      if (!hasPermission) {
        this.speechRecognition.requestPermission();
      }
    });
  }

  startListening() {
    let options = {
      showPopup: true,
      language: "en-US",
    };
    this.speechRecognition.startListening(options).subscribe((matches) => {
      this.matches = matches;
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    });
    this.isRecording = true;
  }

  stopListening() {
    this.speechRecognition.stopListening().then(() => {
      this.isRecording = false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Adding the above code to AndroidManifest.xml has solved my problem. Ionic Cordova Speech Recognition is working with Android 11.

Answer (score -1):

Though in my case environment is not ionic, but cordova only. I checked android10 and 7,8 devices, they are working. The corresponding APIs of android SDK is downloaded, cordova-plugin-speechrecognition is installed, and cordova version is v11.0.

I know it does not work android11 device, so I have been finding solution.
According several informations, androidManifest.xml seems to include "android.speech.RecognitionService".
But I don't know how to do...